# How to write a CSS selector that works on nested divs and selects the closest match?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Imagine I have a dynamically rendered page where I use classes `class1` and `class2` on some divs which contain each other:

```html
<div class="class1">
  ...
  <div class="class2">
    ...
    <div class="insider">
```

I also have these selectors in my CSS:

```css
.class1 .insider { ... }
.class2 .insider { ... }
```

Now the problem is that both selectors match the above `.insider` and the one later in the CSS source code will win. 
**How can I make the selector win that has the `classN` parent closest  to the `.insider`.**

---

Below is a snippet where I reproduced my problem, I also showed my expectations with inline styles.
The `.other` and `.another` `div`s are there to show that the depth of .insider is not known, so the direct child selector (`>`) is out of the picture.

```css
/* Layout: irrelevant to the issue */
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 25px 25px;
}
.insider {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Colors: the visual part that should be fixed */
.class1 {
  background-color: black;
}
.class2 {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.class1 .insider {
  color: red;
}
.class2 .insider {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Title</th><th>Actual</th><th>Expected</th><th>Explanation</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class1-2</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer class1">
    <div class="inner class2">
      <div class="other">
        <p class="insider">asdf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <div class="other">
        <p class="insider" style="color: green;">asdf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be green because the closest styled parent is "class2" and not because ".class2 .insider" is declared after ".class1 .insider" in the CSS code. Swap the red and green styles in CSS and the text turns red.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class2-1</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer class2">
    <div class="inner class1">
      <div class="other">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: black;">
      <div class="other">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider" style="color: red;">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be red because the closest styled parent is "class1".</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class2-1-2</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer class2">
    <div class="inner class1">
      <div class="other class2">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: black;">
      <div class="other" style="background-color: lightgray;">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider" style="color: green;">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be green because the closest styled parent is "class2", and not because the outermost styled parent is "class2", nor because of declaration order, see the first case.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

All of the examples show this in the Chrome Dev Tools Inspector:
[image]
where it's visible that the green color wins because it has bigger line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.class1 .insider,
.class2 .class1 .insider{
  color: red;
}
.class2 .insider,
.class1 .class2 .insider{
  color: green;
}
```

The downside of this solution is as your N increase the number of selector you have to write also increase recursively. But it can be helped with a pre-processing library like SASS or LESS.

Demo:

```css
/* Layout: irrelevant to the issue */
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 25px 25px;
}
.insider {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Colors: the visual part that should be fixed */
.class1 {
  background-color: black;
}
.class2 {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.class1 .insider,
.class2 .class1 .insider{
  color: red;
}
.class2 .insider,
.class1 .class2 .insider{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Title</th><th>Actual</th><th>Expected</th><th>Explanation</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class1-2</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer class1">
    <div class="inner class2">
      <div class="other">
        <p class="insider">asdf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <div class="other">
        <p class="insider" style="color: green;">asdf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be green because the closest styled parent is "class2" and not because ".class2 .insider" is declared after ".class1 .insider" in the CSS code. Swap the red and green styles in CSS and the text turns red.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class2-1</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer class2">
    <div class="inner class1">
      <div class="other">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: black;">
      <div class="other">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider" style="color: red;">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be red because the closest styled parent is "class1".</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class2-1-2</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer class2">
    <div class="inner class1">
      <div class="other class2">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: black;">
      <div class="other" style="background-color: lightgray;">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider" style="color: green;">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be green because the closest styled parent is "class2", and not because the outermost styled parent is "class2", nor because of declaration order, see the first case.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

Edit with another N-independent version in which you only need to add selectors if your nested HTML layout get more complex:

```
.unique_class_name1 .insider,
[class~=unique_class_name] .unique_class_name1 .insider{
  color: red;
}
.unique_class_name2 .insider,
[class~=unique_class_name] .unique_class_name2 .insider{
  color: green;
}
```

In this version though, it is very important to make sure the pattern `unique_class_name` is truly unique, since `class~=unique_class_name` will hit all elements where the class attribute contains that key.

```css
/* Layout: irrelevant to the issue */
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 25px 25px;
}
.insider {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Colors: the visual part that should be fixed */
.unique_class_name1 {
  background-color: black;
}
.unique_class_name2 {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.unique_class_name1 .insider,
[class~=unique_class_name] .unique_class_name1 .insider{
  color: red;
}
.unique_class_name2 .insider,
[class~=unique_class_name] .unique_class_name2 .insider{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Title</th><th>Actual</th><th>Expected</th><th>Explanation</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class1-2</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer unique_class_name1">
    <div class="inner unique_class_name2">
      <div class="other">
        <p class="insider">asdf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <div class="other">
        <p class="insider" style="color: green;">asdf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be green because the closest styled parent is "class2" and not because ".class2 .insider" is declared after ".class1 .insider" in the CSS code. Swap the red and green styles in CSS and the text turns red.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class2-1</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer unique_class_name2">
    <div class="inner unique_class_name1">
      <div class="other">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: black;">
      <div class="other">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider" style="color: red;">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be red because the closest styled parent is "class1".</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inside class2-1-2</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer unique_class_name2">
    <div class="inner unique_class_name1">
      <div class="other unique_class_name2">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="outer" style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color: black;">
      <div class="other" style="background-color: lightgray;">
        <div class="another">
          <p class="insider" style="color: green;">asdf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>The text color should be green because the closest styled parent is "class2", and not because the outermost styled parent is "class2", nor because of declaration order, see the first case.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [Alohci](http://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci) had a similar idea in a comment on another answer here, but he removed it. I guess he noticed it was the same as your edit.

Comment: This works well, but only for a limited amount of nesting, the `[class]` part of the selector has to be multiplied a few times to match each level (I used X just to show the pattern, it has to be long and unique as Av said): `.X1, [class~=X] .X1, [class~=X] [class~=X] .X1, [class~=X] [class~=X] [class~=X] .X1, ...`, and the one with the highest specificity wins, which will be the deepest match for that `Xi`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying both rules for nesting and not nesting elements?

Like `.c1 .c2 .insider, .c2 .insider { color: red;}`

Other way would be to refactor your code.

```css
.c2 .c1 .c3,
.c1 .c3 {
  color: green;

}

.c1 .c2 .c3,
.c2 .c3 {
  color: blue;

}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="c3">C2 - blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="c2">
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c3">C1 - green</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c3">C1 - green</div>
</div>
<div class="c2">
  <div class="c3">C2 - blue</div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this solution OP needs to write all possible combinations, that can be infinite. I think this topic is better achieved with javascript... I think.

Comment: @Justinas add another `<div class="c1">` around your whole code and it breaks. Though it may work if I can guarantee that the nesting depth of c1/c2 cannot be greater than `N`, but still have to generate `~N!` selectors...

Answer (score 2):

I think your only option outside of javascript would be to set the insider class to inherit and set the color in the containing divs

```
.class1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
}
.class2 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: green;
}
.insider {
  color: inherit;
}
```

---

Heres a javascript jquery approach using a couple of css classes depending on which is nearest

```
.class2nearest{
  color:green;
}

.class1nearest{
  color:red;
}
```

Then use this jquery which finds the closest of class1 or class2 and gets its class, appends the nearest text to match the desired css class to apply, a bit clucky but should work as intended.

```
$('.insider').each(function(){
     $(this).addClass($(this).closest('.class1,.class2').attr('class')+'nearest');
  });
```

---

Code snippet using the layout in OPs comment

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.insider').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).closest('.class1,.class2').attr('class') + 'nearest');
  });
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: grey;
}
.class2 {
  background-color: white;
}
.class2nearest {
  color: red;
}
.class1nearest {
  color: green;
}
.class2nearest {} .class1nearest {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="insider">
      TEXT1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class2">
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="insider">
      TEXT 2
      <div class="class2">
        <div class="insider">
          TEXT3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- below is structure from OP's comment -->
<div class="class1">
  <div class="insider">TEXT4</div>
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="insider">TEXT5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which shows its the nearest containing class that matches.

Comment: That makes sense and I think that's the best approach with CSS. There are not another solution with purecss. My upvote :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, that actually answers this question. The problem is that it cannot be extended if you have multiple `.insider` classes (like in a code highlighter).

Comment: @TWiStErRob I've added a jquery approach which may be of interest

Comment: I'm not sure that `nearest` suffix works, think about this case: `<div.class1><div.insider /><div.class2><div.insider /></div></div>` each `.insider` would match one of the `.classX` as the closest one, so both will get the suffix and we're back to square one.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I've added a snippet which shows it does match the closest parent, so for the example structure it seems to work fine. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Take another look at my example, notice the slashes: the first `.insider` and `.class2` are siblings inside `.class1`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob they are in the code snippet as well, look at the part below the comment

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the inner div is ever with `.insider` classname, you can make with jquery (as we talk in comments) easy as this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.insider').each(function() {
    var color = $(this).parent().css('color');
    $(this).css('color', color);  //override the .insider with the parent color
  });
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  color:green;
}
.class2 {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="insider">
      This text have the color of class2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class2">
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="insider">
      This text have the color of class1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We iterate all `.insider` elements, get the color of the parent and override the `.insider` color.

Tell us if this fits with your requirements

Comment: Thank you! I see, so your idea is to copy the style directly, applying the type of rule that I'm looking for. Interesting approach! It may work better with a few enhancements: `parent()` -> `closest('.class1, .class2')` and it's likely better to restructure my CSS selectors so they're like this: `.class1.insider` and propagate the class of the ascendant so it's not restricted to just using the "color" style.

Comment: Yeah you can override all properties you need. The problem is that in css is impossible to target a parent since the children, but with few lines of javascript you can get the behaviour you want. Tell me if you want some improvements.

Comment: Well, are removed. Please, upvote at least this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `closest` to find the closest and update color.

Here is the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gmhw2zpL/

HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="insider">
      This text have the color of class2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class2">
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="insider">
      This text have the color of class1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.insider').each(function() {
    var color = $(this).closest('.class1,.class2').css('color');
    $(this).css('color', color);  //override the .insider with the parent color
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.class1 {
  color:green;
}
.class2 {
  color:red;
}
```

This solution also works if there are divs in between.
Another fiddle with elements in between: https://jsfiddle.net/gmhw2zpL/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can use css selector.
element > element

```css
div > p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>My name is Anil</h2>
  <p>I live in India.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <span>
    <p>I will not be styled.</p>
  </span>
</div>

<p>My best friend is Sunil.</p>
```

Comment: Please read the question: "the depth of .insider is not known, so the direct child selector (>) is out of the picture."

Comment: you can use jquery to find your element class and add class to element.